# Pairs of elements in $F_n$ with distinct translation lengths

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, outer-automorphisms

Let $F_n$ be a free group of rank n and consider all possible non-degenerate length functions on $F_n$.

Could I be directed to a reference that give two non-trivial non-power-conjugate elements $g,h \in F_n$ (i.e. no power of $g$ is conjugate to a power of $h$) such that there is some $K>1$ so that for any length function we have:
$$
\|g\|_T \geq K \cdot \|h\|_T,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_T$ denote translation length for some $T \in \operatorname{CV}_n$? Obviously, we have this if $h^K=g$, but I specifically want a pair of elements that are not powers of one another.

Comment: It amounts to finding $g,h \in F_n$ and $K>1$ such that $\|g\| \geq K \cdot \|h\|$ for every free action on $F_n$ on a tree, right? If $g,h$ are two conjugates of some non-trivial element, what about $gh$ and $g^nh^n$? The point is that $g,h$ have the same translation length $\ell$, and, because the action is free, their axes must have intersection of diameter $\leq \ell$. So it should be possible to determine the axes and translation lengths of $gh$ and $g^nh^n$. (This is maybe a naive idea, I do not have the time to check the details right now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the details, here is a statement that seems to answer your question:

> **Fact:** For every free action of $F_n$ on a real tree $T$ and for all non-commensurated elements $g,h \in F_n$, the inequality $$\|h^kg^k\|_T > \frac{1}{2} \|hg\|_T$$ holds for every $k \geq 2$.

This is an immediate consequence of the following observation:

> **Lemma:** *Let $T$ be a real tree and $g,h \in \mathrm{Isom}(T)$ two independent loxodromic isometries. Assume that* $$\mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h)) < \|g\|,\|h\|.$$ *Then $hg$ is also loxodromic and its translation length is*
>
> - *$\|h\|+ \|g\|$ if $\mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h))>0$ and if the translation directions of $g,h$ agree on the intersection $\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h)$;*
> - *$\|h\|+\|g\| - 2 \cdot \mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h))$ if $\mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h))>0$ and if the translation directions of $g,h$ disagree on the intersection $\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h)$;*
> - *$\|hg\|= \|h\|+\|g\| + 2 \cdot d(\mathrm{Axis}(h), \mathrm{Axis}(g))$ if $\mathrm{diam}(\mathrm{Axis}(g) \cap \mathrm{Axis}(h))=0$.*

The proof is straightforward: it suffices to find a point $x \in T$ such that $hgx$ lies on $[x,(hg)^2x]$ and to compute the distance between $x$ and $hgx$. The different cases are illustrated by the following figures.

[image]

Comment: I think we also need to specify that $h$ and $g$ have distinct axes in the statement of the fact. But yeah, that does the trick!

Comment: Right! I added the assumption, thank you.

Comment: Very nice! The question asks for $K>1$, and this provides $K=1/2+\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @HJRW: Right, I did not pay attention to this condition... But then $\| (h^pg^p)^q\| > \frac{q}{2} \|hg\|$ for all $p,q \geq 2$.

Comment: Good point! :)${}$